# How to keep blank data or assign missing data when recompiuting data for unit shift

Tags: awk, data, math

I have a series of data files with format below. I have a script to read just the data to the needed units (ppm to ppb) thus the *1000 of column $3. The issue which I am running into when awk runs and the data set does not have a value for a given row it is placing "0" when it computes every single row. Is there a way to get awk to leave a given row cell which was blank originally to be blank (or another missing flag as -999) after running?

```
00:00 20101001 0.3
01:00 20101001 0.3
02:00 20101001 0.2
03:00 20101001 0.2
```

---

```
awk -F ' ' '($3<=0.99 && $3>=0) {print $1,$2,$3*1000}' County001-CO-0012.txt > test.out
```

Comment: you are strictly checking that third column has date and then doing calculation, so it won't have problem with your command. if it was  just `awk '{print $1,$2,$3*1000}'`, then yes, what you say would happen. but not now with that command you have it; would you clarify more?

Comment: The data set has is from a main data set of various sensors so all rows will have the data and time. the lack of data in Col3 is due to either an error pick up by system computer or if senor was taken offline during calabration tests

Comment: please use [edit] link under your question to adding more details; also suggested to add expected output and revise your input to show some missing data in column#3, now all rows has data in third col

Comment: The reason for the *1000 adjustment is due to the a change in measurement units set up in observation system. The numberous sites i have have no uniform time when each was changed and do not want to have to go in excel and adjust these files by hand using excel.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need this?

```
awk '($3>0 && 0.99>=$3) { $3*=1000 }1' infile
```

Comment: Thank you that did exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: @stormctr2 you are welcome! please consider to apply this https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers on the answers to your questions https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/396038/stormctr2?tab=questions for which solved your problem